# Variable blank when used in if statement but not echo

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to save value from a curl command to a variable in a bash script.

Script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

curr=$(pwd)
IP_addr="192.168.0.102"
username="root"
password="pass"

HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -IL --silent $username:$password@$IP_addr | grep HTTP)
echo
echo "echo the variable works!"
echo $HTTP_STATUS
isOK=$(echo $HTTP_STATUS)
status="HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"

echo

if [[ $HTTP_STATUS == $status ]]; then
    echo "The same the same!"
else
    echo "$isOK is not the same as $status"
fi

echo

if [ "$status" == "$isOK" ]
then
    echo "The same the same!"
else
    echo "$isOK is not the same as $status"
fi
```

I am deliberately passing the wrong password in order for curl to return HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized. I want a function to check if wrong credentials are sent to a server.

The strange thing is that when I save the output from the curl command ie

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -IL --silent $username:$password@$IP_addr | grep HTTP | tee $curr/test.txt)
```

To a file with tee I get this printed in file HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized. But if I remove the tee command ie

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -IL --silent $username:$password@$IP_addr | grep HTTP)
```

And execute the script I get following print in terminal

```
./test.sh 
echo the variable works!
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

is not the same as HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

is not the same as HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

I tried with following as well but same result

```
HTTP_STATUS=`curl -IL --silent $username:$password@$IP_addr | grep HTTP`
```

The variable HTTP_STATUS seems to be blank when I do the checks in the if statements. How is this possible and why is the output of the command saved to a file with tee and echo the variable works but not when using the variable in the if statements?

Best regards

Comment: *Always* quote your parameter expansions until you learn when it is safe or appropriate to leave them unquoted.

Comment: I found a answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444125/bash-string-command-output-equality-test. For some reason. When using stars ** around "$status" such as *"$status"* it works. But I still don't know why this is!

Comment: The stars create a pattern, which matches any string that starts with a (possibly empty) sequence of characters, then `$status`, then ending with a (possibly empty) sequence of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP protocol requires that header lines end with <CR><LF> (carriage return and line feed, `\r\n` in UNIX notation). To see what `curl` actually returns you can try:

```
curl -IL --silent $username:$password@$IP_addr | grep HTTP | cat -v
```

In UNIX, <LF> terminates the text line, and <CR> is just an ordinary character with no special meaning. The apparently missing `$isOK` in the subsequent messages is due to the trailing <CR>, which moves the cursor back at the beginning of the line. In detail, the line

```
echo "$isOK is not the same as $status"
```

writes out

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized<CR>
 is not the same as HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

both on the same line.